# PNG images generate errors when on linux server node but not on head node

Tags: r, linux, server

My end goal is to render R Markdown documents on my university's Linux server that uses SLURM for queue management. However, using the PNG graphical device generates an error, whilst the PDF graphical device provides inappropriate output.

Note that I have a Windows computer, and am using PuTTY to communicate with the server. Xming is installed, and PuTTY has X11 forwarding enabled.

When I run

```
salloc --ntasks 1 --partition <partition_name>
srun Rscript -e "png('test.png'); plot(1,1); dev.off()"`
```

no plot is saved and I get the following warning messages:

> 1: In png("test.png") :
>
> > unable to load shared object '/opt/exp_soft/R- 3.5.2/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
> >     /lib64/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
>
> 2: In png("test.png") : failed to load cairo DLL
>
> null device

However, when I remove only the `srun` command and run

```
salloc --ntasks 1 --partition <partition_name>
srun Rscript -e "png('test.png'); plot(1,1); dev.off()"`
```

then the file`test.png` is saved. In addition, outputting a PDF rather than a PNG also correctly generates the plot (`Rscript -e "pdf( 'test.pdf'); plot(1,1); dev.off()"`).

In the same way, rendering an Rmd document using `Rscript -e "('test.Rmd')"`without using `srun` at the beginning will correctly render the Rmd doc. But putting `srun` at the start will not generate an Rmd document, and will only generate the warning messages:

> File test2_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.svg not found in resource path
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In grDevices::png(f) :
>     unable to load shared object '/opt/exp_soft/R-3.5.2/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
>     /lib64/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
>
> 2: In grDevices::png(f) : failed to load cairo DLL
>
> 3: In (function (filename = if (onefile) "Rplots.svg" else "Rplot%03d.svg",  :
>     failed to load cairo DLL
>
> Execution halted
>
> srun: error: srvcnthpc100: task 0: Exited with exit code 1

If I set `dev='pdf'` as knitr chunk option, then the Rmd doc is rendered, but the plot in the html doc is very odd, as it has a scroll wheel and a grey background ([dev_equals_png_rmd_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVwC.png)).

I've noted that the "undefined symbol" in the above error message, "FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates", is part of the FreeType library. However, I'm not sure what this may mean or what I would do about it if it meant something.

I re-installed the `Cairo` R package, but that did not change the error messages.

Since the PNG images render on the head node (i.e. without `srun`) but not on the server nodes (i.e. with `srun`), then it seems to me that something is broken down in the communication between `R`, `SLURM` and the server nodes, rather than some files or programs being missing.

I also think that `pandoc` throws an error because the png image was not generated when the `R` code was run.

Note that the above errors are also produced when `sbatch` instead of `srun` is used (i.e. the code run in batch rather than interactive mode).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to working with Linux, and was starting to enjoy it!

Running `Rscript -e "sessionInfo()"` on the server yields:

> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
>
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
> Matrix products: default
>   BLAS: /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2
>   LAPACK: /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.2
>
> locale:
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVwC.png) LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>
> [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
>
> [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
>
> [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
>
> [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
>
> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVwC.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVwC.png) rmarkdown_1.11
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVwC.png) compiler_3.5.2  tools_3.5.2     htmltools_0.3.6 Rcpp_1.0.0
>   [5] knitr_1.21      xfun_0.5        digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13

When I run `Rscript -e capabilities()`, I get the following:

```
jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       TRUE       FALSE
http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv
TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE
NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl
TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was indeed with FreeType. The previous library of FreeType was broken (not sure in what sense exactly, but this is what the system admin said), and the system admin had rolled out the updated and fixed FreeType. However, he had accidentally only done this on the head node and the server node he tested on. Once he updated the entire cluster, the code ran as expected. Both straight PNG plots and rendering Rmd docs with graphics worked fine.